# "docker run swarm create" failed with error "503 Service Unavailable"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

My platform is :

- OS: `Ubuntu-16.04`
- Docker version: `1.12.6, build 78d1802`

When I ran `docker run swarm create`, it failed with following output:

```
Unable to find image 'swarm:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/swarm
ebe0176dcf9a: Pull complete
19f771faa982: Pull complete
902eeedf931a: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:815fc8fd4617d866e1256999c2c0a55cc8f377f3dade26c3edde3f0543a70c04
Status: Downloaded newer image for swarm:latest
<html><body><h1>**503 Service Unavailable**</h1>
**No server is available to handle this request.**
</body></html>
```

I was doing POC on swarm to orchestrate different docker containers but not able to proceed. Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The might be some confusion in what you've done.

`docker run swarm create` is **not** how you can create a swarm cluster with docker 1.12+.

I don't know precisely what the `library/swarm` container is for, but definitely not for operating a swarm cluster (maybe an old way for it?).

The command to create a swarm cluster with Docker version 1.12+, on your **manager** node, is :

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <MANAGER-IP>
```

You can have a look at this [official docker swarm tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/) to do your POC.

Comment: Ok. I was confused between two. I will Try the POC with that tutorial. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @user1662655 you're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you like it